# No output on screen. When I'm reading file it's not giving output

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import time


name = open('list.txt','a+')
print ("When file was opened the pointer was at", name.tell())
name.write('It\'s all about mindset.')
time.sleep(2)
print ("Writing your script.... Wait for some time...")
name.close()
name = open('list.txt','r')
string = name.read(0)
print('Final output is:'`
print (string)
name.close()
```

I am currently learning python file operations. The above code is not working properly. It's not reading the file.

Comment: How much data do you think `name.read(0)` reads?  What do you think the argument of zero specifies?

Comment: I got it... It should be name.read() or name.read(-1). To read all the document from beginning. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `0` from `string = name.read(0)` to show all or write a number bigger than `0`.
that's the length of characters should be shown.